# TypeError: jest.fn(...).mockResolvedValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I just upgraded to jest 24.9.0 and some of my tests are now getting the error: `TypeError: jest.fn(...).mockResolvedValue is not a function`

With this code:

```
describe('comments', () => {
    it('should create a comment', async () => {
      const comment = {
        body: 'here is a comment',
      };
      const fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
        status: 200,
        json: () => comment
      });

      const resolver = getResolver({ fetch });
      ...
```

Comment: Did you solve this?